# What balances the weight of a horizontally rotating object?

Tags: forces, orbital-motion, centripetal-force, weight

When an object is made to rotate in a horizontal circle:

1. Why does the angle between the plane of rotation and the horizontal decrease if the speed of rotation increases?
2. What force balances the weight of the rotating object preventing it from falling down?[image: What is the force represented by "?" ?]

Comment: Horizontal circle is always possible, but the string cannot be horizontal. See [conical pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_pendulum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no force, which pulls the weight up except for the vertical component of the tension.

For this reason a vertical component  of the tension is always there, thus the angle cannot be zero.

If you write down Newton's second law, assuming that the tension has both
a vertical, and horizontal component, you'll find that as the speed of rotation goes to infinity, the angle goes to zero.

Comment: So, its impossible to spin things horizontally? Also, why does the angle decrease when you spin things faster?

Comment: In order for it spin horizontal, you need infinite speed. As I said, the decrease in the angle is a direct outcome of Newton's 2nd law for your system.